# Setting a Revolution Slider 5+ layer to appear as a static layer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, revolution-slider

I would like to have a shape beneath my text on all slides to remain static throughout and not flicker in and out.

I know that Revolution Slider has an option for static layers, but it doesn't allow you to layer it **beneath** layers in other slides, it's always on top.

I tried creating a layer in each slide with 0 transitions, but when I set everything to 0, it disappears.

How to I either:
1. Create a static layer that can be layered beneath other layers
2. Set the transitions on my layers within slides to eliminate transitioning in and out so that the layer appears to be a static layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a good question because there is probably no way that you can do that perfectly in revolution 5 if you don't want to use background image beneath the text.

This should be handled with static/global layer for the layer that is on the bottom, but rev5 will always override your z-index (or anything else that you try in this manner) and it will always appear on top. So nothing here.

Other thing to do is to put this layer on every slide, always on the same position and turn off all animations on that layer so that he behaves static on every slide. But rev5 altough you defined that there is no animation uses animation speed parameter and that layer will flicker again. If you put that the animation speed is 0, the layer will dissapear. Why is that probably creators of the slider doesn't know either.

Only thing that I think you can do is to trick him to appear like you want, it will not be perfect, but maybe acceptable.

So on the bottom (static) layer click on the Animation in the menu above and choose No-Animation and No-Out Animation. Since you can't put 0 to animation speed we will put the speed 100 for in animation and 1000 for out animation. In this way out animation will be long enough to appear that the layer is animating continuous - that is static. But even with this the layer flickers slightly, but much much less then before, so maybe the effect is acceptable.

You can play with fade in instead of no-animation, and with animation speed numbers, trick is that the out speed last long enough for the in speed of the next slide to kick in.

I hope this will help, I would also love for rev 5 creators to solve this issue.

Comment: I ended up doing your second suggestion: playing around with the animations. no animations on the actual layer, I then make start time 1, start speed 1 (to prevent from not appearing at all as when you set to 0), and then making the end time overlap into the next slide. It works for now, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem today, and i don't agree with the accepted answer, because you can easily change the z-index of static layers with a css override.

Revolution slider has a build-in custom css editor, so go to your Slider settings, scroll to the bottom and add:

```
.tp-static-layers {
z-index: 0;
}
```

Done, all static layers will appear beneath normal layers.

### EDIT

With newer versions of revslider each slide `<li>` container has a z-index. Try the following css.

```
.tp-static-layers {
  z-index: 1;
}
ul.tp-revslider-mainul > li {
  z-index: unset !important;
}
```

NOTE: Not fully tested, it's possible this may interfere with animations.